# Show sources in VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sharpdevelop

How can I configure VS 2010 to show the .NET sources, as Sharp Develop does?  I don't need to debug .NET framework code, I only want to navigate to the sources.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a built in feature of Visual Studio 2010. You can however install [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) + [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). Then press F12 on a .NET class, like `String`, and choose to decompile the sources. It will show you the decompiled .NET source code.

Comment: Decompile the class = see the source code. What do you think, how does Sharp Develop get the source code?